# Refactor Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m really new into Angular and Javascript and I have Angular select like this:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

And I have one function inside another function into controller but I want to separate those functions.

I have something like this:

```
$scope.filtro = function(selected) {
                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;

                $scope.insertar = function() {
                    $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
                    if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {....
```

But I want to close one `$scope.filtro` before open `$scope.insertar` and then call  `$scope.selectedID` of `$scope.filtro` and call into  `$scope.insertar`, how can I do that change? Regards

**UPDATE**

As Sajeetharan  comment I do

```
 $scope.filtro = function (selected) {
            $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
            $scope.insertar(selected);
        }

        $scope.insertar = function (selected) {
                    $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
                    if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {
```

But I getting `selected is udefined`. can anyone help me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the second function inside the first,

```
$scope.filtro = function(selected) {
 $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
 $scope.insertar(selected);
}
$scope.insertar = function(selected) {
 $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
}
```

Comment: I do it, but I just gettin selected is not defined

Comment: try updating $scope.insertar = function(selected) {

Comment: keep getting undefined :/

Comment: which one is getting undefined?

Comment: selected is undefined

Comment: is it getting passed in the first function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148747/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ledwing).